# Changing LinkButton Onclick event

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling, asplinkbutton

I'm trying to create LinkButtons Dynamically and change their onclick event from the server side like this:

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= pagenum; i++)
    {
        LinkButton pb = new LinkButton();
        pb.Text=i.ToString();
        pb.CommandArgument=i.ToString();
        pb.ID = "PageLink" + i.ToString()+",";
        pb.Click += new EventHandler(Method1);
        pb.Visible = true;
        PagesDiv.Controls.Add(pb);
    }

 public void Method1(object sender, EventArgs e, int pagenum)
{
    PagesDiv.Visible = true;
    TableDiv.Visible = true;
    localhost.StorageService w = new localhost.StorageService();
    DataTable dt = w.GetItemsByCategory(pagenum, categoryname.ToString());
    .................................(alot of code here...)
}
```

But my problem is that i'm getting an error on "pb.Click += new EventHandler(Method1);"
saying: "No overload for 'Method1' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'"
I can't seem to find why it is not working...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

You've added an extra parameter to your event handler.  So it doesn't match [the `Click` event handler on `LinkButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.click.aspx).  Look at yours:

```
public void Method1(object sender, EventArgs e, int pagenum)
```

And look at what it expects:

```
public void Method1(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Hence, the error.  I'm not sure how you expect `pagenum` to be passed in this case anyway, since it's not mentioned in the handler assignment:

```
pb.Click += new EventHandler(Method1);
```

There may be some other tricks to pass an argument to a handler, but one that's always worked for me and seems pretty straightforward is to simply wrap it in a lambda function:

```
pb.Click += (sender, e) => Method1(sender, e, pagenum);
```

This creates an anonymous method which just calls your method after capturing the value of `pagenum`, whatever that happens to be in the calling code.